# prestashop - how to have 2 prices per product, 1 for pack (50 items) and one for case (500 items)?

Tags: prestashop

My client sends only stocks. For each product, he has 2 prices: 'pack' for 50 pieces, 'case' for 500 pieces.

In the frontend, I should display both for each product, with 2 quantity fields, one for each type. For example:

Product X

```
pack 50 (40$): [qty field]
case 500 (100$): [qty field]
```

how can I do it?

I'm a php and js programmer, you can speak tech if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way for you to achieve this is by using the **attributes** to create **combinations**.

For this, you can:

- Go to **Catalog > Attributes and Values**
- Create a new **Attribute** (e.g. Pack)
- Create new values for that attribute: **Pack 50**; and **Case 500**
- Now go to **Catalog > Products** and choose your product
- Choose the **Combination** tab and from there, you can use the **Product combinations generator** and specify everything you need: price, reference, weight.

For more information with images and so on, please refer to the [PrestaShop User Guide section about combinations](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Adding+Products+and+Product+Categories#AddingProductsandProductCategories-AddingProductCombinations)

Comment: Yes, I confirm, that's teh way. I already did it. Thank you anyway.